# Convert char to date - Hive

Tags: sql, date, hive, type-conversion

I need concat 2 columns char in 1 column date.
I tried it:

```
INSERT INTO tb_teste PARTITION (dt_originacao_fcdr)
SELECT
tp_registro_fcdr,
seq_registro_fcdr,
tp_cdr_fcdr,
dt_atendimento_fcdr,
date_dt_atendimento_fcdr,
hr_atendimento_fcdr,
timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CONCAT(dt_atendimento_fcdr, hr_atendimento_fcdr), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as date_hr_atendimento_fcdr,
duracao_atend_fcdr,
hr_originacao_fcdr,
duracao_total_fcdr,
duracao_chamada_tarifada_fcdr,
st_chamada_fcdr,
fim_sel_orig_fcdr,
numero_a_fcdr,
tp_numero_a_fcdr,
numero_b_fcdr,
tp_numero_b_fcdr,
numero_b_orig_fcdr,
numero_c_fcdr,
tp_numero_c_fcdr,
tp_trafego_fcdr,
esn_fcdr,
central_fcdr,
erb_fcdr,
tp_erb_fcdr,
face_erb_inici_fcdr,
erb_final_fcdr,
face_erb_final_fcdr,
erb_original_fcdr,
imsi_fcdr,
imei_fcdr,
tecnologia_fcdr,
cd_oper_ass_a_fcdr,
cd_oper_ass_b_fcdr,
cgi_fcdr,
nu_tlfn_fcdr,
tp_tlfn_fcdr,
tp_tarifa_fcdr,
ident_num_a_fcdr,
ident_num_b_fcdr,
cd_prestadora_fcdr,
cna_orig_ar_erb_fcdr
FROM tb_op_nor;
```

Result: **date_hr_atendimento_fcdr            2019-03-03**

The column containing the time and date is not null or empty.
Example:

[image]
[image]

Time zone: Brazil.

I need date and time in the same columns.

Comment: Please add input and expected output in a table format. This link might help: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-to-create-a-table-in-a-stack-overflow-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `concat` two fields then `unix_timestamp` and by using `from_unixtimestamp` function we can format the output timestamp.

```
with cte as (select stack(1,"20190303","131615") as (dt,hr)) --sample data
select 
timestamp( --cast to timestamp
        from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(dt,hr),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") --concat and change the format
        ) 
from cte
```

**`Output:`**

```
2019-03-03 13:16:15.0
```

If you want to convert to brazil time to UTC or vice versa then use [to_utc_timestamp/from_utc_timestamp](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF).

Comment: Thanks, Shu. I tried this: ```CAST(timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CONCAT(dt_atendimento_fcdr, hr_atendimento_fcdr), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) as date_hr_atendimento_fcdr```, but failed: extraneous input ')' expecting AS near 'as' in primitive type specification (state=42000,code=40000). Can you help me, please?

Comment: @LetíciaBoniottiFerreira, Try this once `timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CONCAT(dt_atendimento_fcdr, hr_atendimento_fcdr), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as date_hr_atendimento_fcdr`, timestamp() means we are **casting to timestamp** here!, **no need to keep cast()** again..

Comment: Now, its works. But, my output continues just date, without time. date_hr_atendimento_fcdr  -> 2019-03-03

Comment: @LetíciaBoniottiFerreira, Could you update the question with your select statement and sample data please?

Comment: Ok. sample data is in the question.